# Sign-in with GitHub no longer available on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, login, stack-exchange

I was logged into [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) (dba.se) using the "Sign in with GitHub" feature. Today when I loaded the site, my account was logged out and the GitHub login method was no longer available.

"Sign in with GitHub" is available from the login link for Stack Overflow, hence my being able to post here. But it is now absent from the login methods for dba.se (as well as meta.stackexchange and SE itself).

Can this feature be restored on the stackexchange.com sites?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4228193/mpag?tab=profile is verification that I have an account over at dba.se (see also https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/52150/mpag).

Comment: GitHub login was only ever supported on Stack Overflow. In the past, logging in on Stack Overflow logged you into all sites. Recent browser security updates have broken that feature for many, so it's no longer possible for your SO login to transfer to other sites, which means it's now not possible to login elsewhere without using another credential. Related: [Let us sign in with GitHub on all Stack Exchange sites, not only Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340877/let-us-sign-in-with-github-on-all-stack-exchange-sites-not-only-stack-overflow)

Comment: Thanks for providing me a starting point for getting past this. I have turned off Firefox's Enhanced Tracking Protection for both SO and SE, but my login here doesn't seem to transfer to SE. Is there another domain that I need to unblock to facilitate the shared login cookie, or is that functionality no longer possible?